# How to remove html tag of Html.Raw

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to out on my page text from database table. Table field "Text" Contains text with html formatting tags

I want to show text without html tag, i use

> @Html.Raw(tour.Description)

I want to remove all style of this and show text only without formating.